# Calculate ever expanding number of columns with data to the right

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Currently have a spreadsheet that tracks attendance. First column is name, second column is attendance % and contains the formula I need to revise, subsequent columns simply have an X or O in them and denote whether someone attended or not (headers for these columns are dates).

Currently using a `COUNTIF()` I can check how many X's there are and then the formula is `SUM(100/no_of_columns*COUNTIF(A3:A12))`

Ideally I want to firstly replace `no_of_columns` with the actual number of columns with data to the right.

I've thought about replacing this with a `SUM(COUNTIF('X')+COUNTIF('O'))` but it seems pretty messy?

Secondly I want to replace the A12 with whatever the last column value is.

I could just make the last column a very high column value, but again feels messy and would like to know if there is a better way...

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rjnUQP7V-U1EZTp3Z8yO7HybBCuQjf2y4LJ4Dv4ctF8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: @player0 Example sheet added

Answer (score 0):

Presume you only have the attendance dates in Row 1 without other information such as headers for Column A and B,

Put the following formula in Cell `B2` and drag it down,

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(OFFSET($C2,,,,COUNTA($1:$1)),),"x")/COUNTA($1:$1)*100
```

> The logic is to use **INDEX + OFFSET** function to dynamically return the range of columns on the right, and use **COUNTA** to find out how many dates are there, and you should understand the use of **COUNTIF**, the calculation is self-explanatory.

**EDIT #2**

After looking into your worksheet, I guess you are adding the new dates by inserting columns between B and C so you probably want to use the following formula in Cell `B2` instead to avoid the system shifting the starting cell reference automatically:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(OFFSET($B2,,1,,COUNTA($1:$1)),),"x")/COUNTA($1:$1)*100
```

> The logic is the same as the previous one but just a little change to the **OFFSET** references so it starts looking for the range from Column B instead of C.

I have tested the above in both Excel and Google-sheets working just fine. Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: About to head to bed but will check tomorrow, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

paste in **B2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
         MMULT(IF(INDIRECT("C2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A2:A), MAX(IF(1:1<>"", COLUMN(1:1), ))))="x", 1, 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(INDIRECT("C2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A2:A), MAX(IF(1:1<>"", COLUMN(1:1), )))))^0))/
         MMULT(IF(INDIRECT("C2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A2:A), MAX(IF(1:1<>"", COLUMN(1:1), ))))<>"", 1, 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(INDIRECT("C2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A2:A), MAX(IF(1:1<>"", COLUMN(1:1), )))))^0))*100, ), 0))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_VxUZI9lmsliR3Tyc5-qjLpq50oVRa8Y18rR-KyhvNc/copy)